# Python tkinter list stores correct value from only 1 group of radiobuttons, next groups delete complete list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tkinter, radio-button

When i click an radio button it gives me the correct value, but when I select the next radio button from another group they delete my first value from the dictionary

Here's the code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

class Main_frame():

    def __init__(self):
        self._title  = 'Radiobutton Test'
        self._resize = False
        self.set_mainframe_size_for_geometry(350, 200)
        self.create_mainframe()

    def create_mainframe(self):
        self.mainframe = Tk()
        self.mainframe.title(self._title)
        self.mainframe.geometry(self.get_mainframe_size_for_geometry())
        self.mainframe.resizable(self._resize, self._resize)

    def set_mainframe_size_for_geometry(self, mainframe_width, mainframe_height):
        self._mainframe_size_for_geometry = str(mainframe_width) + 'x' + str(mainframe_height)

    def get_mainframe_size_for_geometry(self):
        return self._mainframe_size_for_geometry


class Create_Radiobutton():

    def __init__(self,frame, name, positionx, positiony, group, value, buttons):
        self.group                             = None
        self._set_frame_to_insert_radiobutton   = frame
        self._radiobutton_label                 = name
        self._radiobutton_horizontal_position   = positionx
        self._radiobutton_vertical_position     = positiony
        self._radiobutton_group                 = group
        self._radiobutton_value                 = value
        self.get_intvar()
        self.create_radiobutton()
        self._radiobutton_controller = Radiobutton_controller(buttons)

    def create_radiobutton(self):
        self.set_radiobutton(Radiobutton(self._set_frame_to_insert_radiobutton,
                                            text=self._radiobutton_label,
                                            variable=self.group,
                                            value=self._radiobutton_value,
                                            command= lambda : self._radiobutton_controller.main_method(self.group.get())))
        self.get_radiobutton().place(x=self._radiobutton_horizontal_position,
                                     y=self._radiobutton_vertical_position)

    def set_radiobutton(self, radiobutton):
        self._radiobutton = radiobutton

    def get_radiobutton(self):
        return self._radiobutton

    # here is the method to set the IntVar() for each group
    def get_intvar(self):
        self.group = self._radiobutton_group
        if self._radiobutton_group == 1:
            self.group = IntVar(value=1)
        elif self._radiobutton_group == 2:
            self.group = IntVar(value=3)
        elif self._radiobutton_group == 3:
            self.group = IntVar(value=5)

class Radiobutton_controller():

    """
            here is the constructor from radiobutton_controller
            with the list dictionarys_with_active_values
    """
    def __init__(self, button):
        self.button = button
        self.list_with_correct_values = [[], [], []]

    """
           from here i excecute the method
           self.get_radiobutton_value(intvar_value) to fill the list with 
           values
    """
    def main_method(self, intvar_value):
        self.get_radiobutton_value(intvar_value)
        print(self.list_with_correct_values)

    def get_checkbutton1(self):
        for element in self.button:
            return self.button['Checkbutton1'].get()

    def get_checkbutton2(self):
        for element in self.button:
            return self.button['Checkbutton1'].get()

    """
          in this method i put the value in the list
    """
    def get_radiobutton_value(self, intvar_value):
        if intvar_value > 0 and intvar_value <= 2:
            self.list_with_correct_values[0].clear()
            self.list_with_correct_values[0].append(intvar_value)
        if self.get_checkbutton1() == 1:
            if intvar_value > 2 and intvar_value <= 4:
                self.list_with_correct_values[1].clear()
                self.list_with_correct_values[1].append(intvar_value)
        else:
            self.list_with_correct_values[1].clear()
            self.list_with_correct_values[1].append(0)
        if self.get_checkbutton2() == 1:
            if intvar_value > 4 and intvar_value <= 6:
                self.list_with_correct_values[2].clear()
                self.list_with_correct_values[2].append(intvar_value)
        else:
            self.list_with_correct_values[2].clear()
            self.list_with_correct_values[2].append(0)



class Build_Application():

    def main(self):
        self.radiobutton_dictionary = {}
        self.mainframe = Main_frame()
        self.radio1 = Create_Radiobutton(self.mainframe.mainframe,'radio1', 10, 10, 1, 1, self.radiobutton_dictionary)
        self.radio2 = Create_Radiobutton(self.mainframe.mainframe,'radio2', 100, 10, 1, 2, self.radiobutton_dictionary)
        self.radio3 = Create_Radiobutton(self.mainframe.mainframe,'radio3', 10, 50, 2, 3, self.radiobutton_dictionary)
        self.radio4 = Create_Radiobutton(self.mainframe.mainframe,'radio4', 100, 50, 2, 4, self.radiobutton_dictionary)
        self.radio5 = Create_Radiobutton(self.mainframe.mainframe,'radio5', 10, 100, 3, 5, self.radiobutton_dictionary)
        self.radio6 = Create_Radiobutton(self.mainframe.mainframe,'radio6', 100, 100, 3, 6, self.radiobutton_dictionary)

        self.checkbox1 = IntVar()
        self.checkbox2 = IntVar()
        self.checkbutton1 = Checkbutton(self.mainframe.mainframe, text='Disable/Enable', variable=self.checkbox1).place(x=200, y=50)
        self.checkbutton1 = Checkbutton(self.mainframe.mainframe, text='Disable/Enable', variable=self.checkbox2).place(x=200, y=100)

        self.radiobutton_dictionary['Radio1'] = self.radio1
        self.radiobutton_dictionary['Radio2'] = self.radio2
        self.radiobutton_dictionary['Radio3'] = self.radio3
        self.radiobutton_dictionary['Radio4'] = self.radio4
        self.radiobutton_dictionary['Radio5'] = self.radio5
        self.radiobutton_dictionary['Radio6'] = self.radio6
        self.radiobutton_dictionary['Checkbutton1'] = self.checkbox1
        self.radiobutton_dictionary['Checkbutton2'] = self.checkbox2

        self.mainframe.mainframe.mainloop()

app = Build_Application()
app.main()
```

output from main_method (print):

Select radiobutton1 (group1)

```
[[1], [0], [0]]
```

Select radiobutton2 (group1)

```
[[2], [0], [0]]
```

Select radiobutton3 (group2)

```
[[], [3], [0]]
```

Select radiobutton4 (group2)

```
[[], [4], [0]]
```

Select radiobutton5 (group3)

```
[[], [0], [5]]
```

Select radiobutton6 (group3)

```
[[], [], [6]]
```

I don't know what is the problem.

The next problem I discovered, after a button has been selected in each group, there are three values in the list but there is only 1.

for example:

I select the radio buttons 1, 4 and 6
I think the output must be

```
[[1],[4],[6]]
```

but it's not.

Comment: There's too much code here. There's also too much code missing. When you say _"they delete my first value from the dictionary"_, I have no idea which dictionary you're referring to. When you say _"this is the output from main_method"_, that doesn't help me identify the problem in any way because 1) I don't know the parameters you've passed to the function and 2) I don't know the attribute values of the Radiobutton_controller. Please provide a [mcve]. Post code that _runs_, and make it _short_.

Comment: i edited it and now there are only code there is important for the solution, and i hope it is some more readable

Comment: It's definitely a lot more readable, but it doesn't reproduce the problem. You've given us 2 classes with 5 functions, so a total 7 puzzle pieces that we have to put together with glue to complete the puzzle so we can reproduce the underspecified problem. Your code still doesn't run and I still have no idea which dictionary you're talking about.

Comment: okay gimme a sec to make a small runable code :)

Comment: so a little bit bigger as before, but its only this what is needed and it is runable and you can see the problem (i hope so) :)

Comment: i've deleted my Answer but it still there ? need it some time so disapear ? and thank you for editing my question, i think it was better when i answer that other people can see the original question but now i think is better to edit it, and dont answer with some new question that are no answers :)

Comment: You can still see it because it's your own answer and you can undelete it if you choose to. But it's been correctly deleted, don't worry.

Comment: ah okay thank you :D

Comment: Well, one problem is that you're using integers as the `group` for the radio buttons. Each group should be an `IntVar()` instead of an integer. That fixes the problem that all radio buttons can be active simultaneously. As for the incorrect output in your weird `[[1], [0], [0]]` list - I have no idea, and I'm not going to debug that. I'm completely lost in your code. I honestly can't figure out what half of it is supposed to do. So I'll leave that to you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

the Problem was that every radiobutton create its "own" controller
but the Multiselection in every group confuse me, i use integer to identifi the group and in the class create_radiobutton i give the button the correct IntVar() for each group but i can select all buttons in a group

I select the radio buttons 1, 4 and 6
and now the Output is:

> [[1],[4],[6]]

I am so Happy to solve (my stupidness) this problem

Here's the code:

```
 import tkinter
from tkinter import *
class Main_frame():

    def __init__(self):
        self._title  = 'Radiobutton Test'
        self._resize = False
        self.set_mainframe_size_for_geometry(350, 200)
        self.create_mainframe()

    def create_mainframe(self):
        self.mainframe = Tk()
        self.mainframe.title(self._title)
        self.mainframe.geometry(self.get_mainframe_size_for_geometry())
        self.mainframe.resizable(self._resize, self._resize)

    def set_mainframe_size_for_geometry(self, mainframe_width, mainframe_height):
        self._mainframe_size_for_geometry = str(mainframe_width) + 'x' + str(mainframe_height)

    def get_mainframe_size_for_geometry(self):
        return self._mainframe_size_for_geometry


class Create_Radiobutton():

    def __init__(self,frame, name, positionx, positiony, group, value, controller):
        self.group                             = IntVar()
        self._set_frame_to_insert_radiobutton   = frame
        self._radiobutton_label                 = name
        self._radiobutton_horizontal_position   = positionx
        self._radiobutton_vertical_position     = positiony
        self._radiobutton_group                 = group
        self._radiobutton_value                 = value
        self.get_intvar()
        self.create_radiobutton()
        self._radiobutton_controller = controller

    def create_radiobutton(self):
        self.set_radiobutton(Radiobutton(self._set_frame_to_insert_radiobutton,
                                            text=self._radiobutton_label,
                                            variable=self.get_group(),
                                            value=self._radiobutton_value,
                                            command= lambda : self._radiobutton_controller.main_method(self.get_group().get())))
        self.get_radiobutton().place(x=self._radiobutton_horizontal_position,
                                     y=self._radiobutton_vertical_position)

    def set_radiobutton(self, radiobutton):
        self._radiobutton = radiobutton

    def get_radiobutton(self):
        return self._radiobutton

    def get_radiobutton_controller(self, radiobutton_controller):
        return self.get_radiobutton().cget(radiobutton_controller)

    # here is the method to set the IntVar() for each group
    def get_intvar(self):
        if self._radiobutton_group == 1:
            self.set_group1()
        elif self._radiobutton_group == 2:
            self.set_group2()
        elif self._radiobutton_group == 3:
            self.set_group3()

    def set_group1(self):
        self.group = IntVar()
    def set_group2(self):
        self.group = IntVar()
    def set_group3(self):
        self.group = IntVar()

    def get_group(self):
        return self.group


class Radiobutton_controller():

    """
            here is the constructor from radiobutton_controller
            with the list dictionarys_with_active_values
    """
    def __init__(self, button):
        self.button = button
        self.list_with_correct_values = [[], [], []]

    """
           from here i excecute the method
           self.get_radiobutton_value(intvar_value) to fill the list with 
           values
    """
    def main_method(self, intvar_value):
        self.get_radiobutton_value(intvar_value)
        print(self.list_with_correct_values)

    def get_checkbutton1(self):
        for element in self.button:
            return self.button['Checkbutton1'].get()

    def get_checkbutton2(self):
        for element in self.button:
            return self.button['Checkbutton1'].get()

    """
          in this method i put the value in the list
    """
    def get_radiobutton_value(self, intvar_value):
        if intvar_value > 0 and intvar_value <= 2:
            self.list_with_correct_values[0].clear()
            self.list_with_correct_values[0].append(intvar_value)
        if self.get_checkbutton1() == 1:
            if intvar_value > 2 and intvar_value <= 4:
                self.list_with_correct_values[1].clear()
                self.list_with_correct_values[1].append(intvar_value)
        else:
            self.list_with_correct_values[1].clear()
            self.list_with_correct_values[1].append(0)
        if self.get_checkbutton2() == 1:
            if intvar_value > 4 and intvar_value <= 6:
                self.list_with_correct_values[2].clear()
                self.list_with_correct_values[2].append(intvar_value)
        else:
            self.list_with_correct_values[2].clear()
            self.list_with_correct_values[2].append(0)

class Build_Application():

    def main(self):
        self.radiobutton_dictionary = {}
        self.radiobutton = {}
        self.controller = Radiobutton_controller(self.radiobutton_dictionary)
        self.mainframe = Main_frame()
        self.radio1 = Create_Radiobutton(self.mainframe.mainframe,'radio1', 10, 10, 1, 1, self.controller)
        self.radio2 = Create_Radiobutton(self.mainframe.mainframe,'radio2', 100, 10, 1, 2, self.controller)
        self.radio3 = Create_Radiobutton(self.mainframe.mainframe,'radio3', 10, 50, 2, 3, self.controller)
        self.radio4 = Create_Radiobutton(self.mainframe.mainframe,'radio4', 100, 50, 2, 4, self.controller)
        self.radio5 = Create_Radiobutton(self.mainframe.mainframe,'radio5', 10, 100, 3, 5, self.controller)
        self.radio6 = Create_Radiobutton(self.mainframe.mainframe,'radio6', 100, 100, 3, 6, self.controller)

        self.checkbox1 = IntVar()
        self.checkbox2 = IntVar()
        self.checkbutton1 = Checkbutton(self.mainframe.mainframe, text='Disable/Enable', variable=self.checkbox1, ).place(x=200, y=50)
        self.checkbutton1 = Checkbutton(self.mainframe.mainframe, text='Disable/Enable', variable=self.checkbox2, ).place(x=200, y=100)

        self.radiobutton_dictionary['Radio1'] = self.radio1
        self.radiobutton_dictionary['Radio2'] = self.radio2
        self.radiobutton_dictionary['Radio3'] = self.radio3
        self.radiobutton_dictionary['Radio4'] = self.radio4
        self.radiobutton_dictionary['Radio5'] = self.radio5
        self.radiobutton_dictionary['Radio6'] = self.radio6
        self.radiobutton['Radio1'] = self.radio1
        self.radiobutton['Radio2'] = self.radio2
        self.radiobutton['Radio3'] = self.radio3
        self.radiobutton['Radio4'] = self.radio4
        self.radiobutton['Radio5'] = self.radio5
        self.radiobutton['Radio6'] = self.radio6
        self.radiobutton_dictionary['Checkbutton1'] = self.checkbox1
        self.radiobutton_dictionary['Checkbutton2'] = self.checkbox2

        self.mainframe.mainframe.mainloop()

app = Build_Application()
app.main()
```